# Chart.JS To Not Start At 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I am attempting to have my chart to **NOT** start at 0.  I have this syntax, which works perfectly ->

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: barChartData,
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        legend: {
            position: 'top',
        },
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Title'
        }
    }
})
```

However, when I try to add in the below - the `beginAtZero` the page will no longer display my chart.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: barChartData,
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: false
                }
            }]
        },
        legend: {
            position: 'top',
        },
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Title'
        }
    }
});
```

What is the proper way to add in the false for start at 0 with Chart.JS

**EDIT**
Per comment below, I added in the missing comma, however the chart still begins at 0?

**EDIT 2** 
Added image below of my data.  I am after the `xAxes` to not start at 0 and I want the `yAxes` to be formatted as currency with $ sign and , commas (if possible)

This is a screenshot of my chart
[image]

**EDIT 3**
This is the `console.log()` of my `JSON` data
`(13) ["Hornsby", 0, 0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 99]
0:"Hornsby"
1:0
2:0
3:100
4:200
5:300
6:400
7:500
8:600
9:700
10:800
11:900
12:99
length:13`

**Edit 4**
I am querying MSSQL and storing the results in an array - then passing the array to JSON for JQuery to parse.  Below is full syntax (excluding DB conenction & query info)

```
<?php
$db->setQuery($sql);
$rows = $db->loadRowList();
$output = array();
foreach( $rows as $row ) {
array_push($output, $row);
} 
$data = json_encode($output[0]);?>

`<div id="container" style="width: 75%;">
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>

<script>
var jsondata = <?php echo $data; ?>;
var values = [];
for (var i in jsondata) {
values.push(jsondata[i]);
}
var labelsarr = Object.keys(jsondata);
var barChartData = {
labels: labelsarr,
datasets: [{
label: 'Dollar Amount',
backgroundColor:'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
borderWidth: 1,
data: values
}]
};
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'bar',
data: barChartData,
options: {
responsive: true,
legend: {
position: 'top',
},
title: {
display: true,
text: 'Sample Data'
}
}
});
</script>
</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: if this is exactly your code you are missing a `,` after scales and before legend

Comment: @Fered - I added in the comma, however it still begins at 0?

Comment: your chart works now? can you also post your chart data?

Comment: @Fered - the chart displays now, but it is ignoring the beginAtZero: false stipulation.  How would I post my chart datea?

Comment: em.. is this a JSON? can you console.log(barChartData) and copy paste it here if its not so big data?

Comment: @Fered - yes it is JSON data, I posted what the output is from console.log

Comment: wait? your dataset has zero values.  the docs say that if you set the flag to true, the scale will include 0 if it is not already included.  This means that if the data already includes zero, and you set it to false, you need to provide another `min` (minimum) starting point ie. `min: 2` - this will adjust the axis to not start at zero (but might hide some of your data)

Comment: @ochi - the range going across the bottom is months, and there is not a 0 month.  I want to start at 1.I would prefer to show month names not numbers...

Comment: Why not exclude that from the data set then? or why not use "jan", "feb", etc for months?

Comment: @ochi - i am using php to query mssql and pass the array over to jquery.  Not sure how I would use text values for the month names>?

Comment: I see... in PHP, you could map them before crafting the response.  You can also map them in JS after receiving the response

Comment: @ochi - above my skillset on that point my friend.  Post an example?

Comment: posted a running answer... let me see if that is what you are looking for.  Also, could you post a complete JSON response? (not just what you see in the console but the actual JSON string)

Comment: @ochi - see my edit.  That is full connection, excluding the actual DB connection & query.  Does that help clarify?  Thank you for the example below, not 100% sure how to implement my syntax to follow your cadence.

Comment: You'd have to show what `jsondata` looks like - as for the arrays, are they always months? (and always 12?) you could simply hard-code them (there are other solutions but given the skill-level, it might just be easier, just saying)

Comment: @ochi - jsondata is what my console.log from edit 3 produces, is that the answer you were after?  Yes, the bottom row is always months Jan - Dec, the numbers going up the right side vary based off monetary value returned in jsondata.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148564/discussion-between-ochi-and-smith-stanley).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unable to reproduce the issue.

It works as long as you have this setting `beginAtZero: false` - this works for the yAxis, however.

It seems that you are looking for handling the array returned.  I would simply modify the chart similar to demo below.

**See demo below**

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var barChartData = {
    labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Hornsby',
      backgroundColor: '#ff0000',
      borderColor: '#ff9900',
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: [0, 0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 99]
    }]
  };

  var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");


  window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: barChartData,
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: false,
            suggestedMin: 3
          }
        }]
      },
      legend: {
        position: 'top',
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Title'
      }
    }
  });
};
```

```css
#canvas {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

**UPDATE**

The code from your PHP/JS could change slightly as well.  Assuming your data looks like this:

> ["Stanley",0,0,10,20,30,50000,400000,70000,700,800,900,1111]

Then you could make these changes (note: I have not tested them)

```
var jsondata = <?php echo $data; ?>;
var values = [];

// Iterate through loop starting at position 1 
// (position zero has a name, not a value)
for (var i=1; i<jsondata.length; i++) {
    values.push(jsondata[i]);  // we end up with 12 values
}

// this could be hard-coded
var labelsarr = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
 ...
// label could be coming from the data set
// the first element in the array has a label, let's use it
label: jsondata[0],
```